# Why am I getting a error when using TransactionScope and Task.WhenAll in my Parallel MySQL Task Implementation in WPF?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, task

My orignal code is using TransactionScope and Async/Await.
There is a DispatcherTimer on my WPF application and there are some code in the tick as below:

```
List<string> connectionString = new List<string>();
foreach (string connStr in connectionString)
{
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        try
        {
            await CallSQL1(connStr);
            await CallSQL2(connStr);
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call Sql Error");
        }
    }
}
```

public function CallSQL1 and CallSQL2 as below

```
public async Task<int> CallSQL1(string connStr)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            await myConn.OpenAsync();
            string sCmd = "INSERT INTO machine_info VALUES ('CCC','099','AOT','2020-02-02 02:00:00')";

            using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCmd, myConn))
            {
                int result = await myCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Occur");
    }
}

public async Task<int> CallSQL2(string connStr)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            await myConn.OpenAsync();
            string sCmd = "INSERT INTO machine_status VALUES ('workpiece','10','IDLE','9','3030-03-03 03:00:00')";

            using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCmd, myConn))
            {
                int result = await myCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Occur");
    }
}
```

List store 3 different database connection information. Every tick, I will connect to 3 database and call 2  function (CallSQL1, CallSQL2), each function will insert data to different table.
If error happened, TransactionScope will make sure it will rollback. Everything work good for now!

And then I am thinking, maybe I can improve it. To make it become parallel work by using Task.Add and Task.WhenAll. So I chagne code as below:

```
List<Task> disTaskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (string connStr in connectionString)
{
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        try
        {
            disTaskList.Add(CallSQL1(connStr));
            disTaskList.Add(CallSQL2(connStr));
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call Sql Error Excption = ");
        }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(disTaskList);
}
```

Now the error show at last line 'await Task.WhenAll(disTaskList);'

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Is there something wrong with my thinking? My idea is If there is error occur, then transactionScope will rollback disTaskList.Add for this database. After foreach 3 database I can await the rest Task in disTaskList.

For Example:

- DB1 CallSQL1 ok -> disTaskList.Add(CallSQL1(connStr)), disTaskList.count = 1.
- DB1 CallSQL2 error -> transactionScope will rollback, disTaskList.count = 0.
- DB2 CallSQL1 ok -> disTaskList.Add(CallSQL1(connStr)), disTaskList.count = 1.
- DB2 CallSQL2 ok -> disTaskList.Add(CallSQL2(connStr)), disTaskList.count = 2.
- DB3 CallSQL1 ok -> disTaskList.Add(CallSQL1(connStr)), disTaskList.count = 3.
- DB3 CallSQL2 ok -> disTaskList.Add(CallSQL2(connStr)), disTaskList.count = 4.

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Executing 2 queries concurrently doesn't mean they'll run faster. If they interfere with each other they may end up not only running slower but *deadlocking* too. Using distributed transactions the way you tried here is not only a lot *slower* but requires explicit server support and configuration.

Comment: If you want to insert lots of rows quickly, using 2 concurrent queries will take more than twice the time as the identical queries conflict with each other. It would be orders of magnitude faster to use an `INSERT` with multiple rows or better yet, [MySqlBulkCopy](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/)

Comment: `Everything work good for now!` not really. What is the actual problem? How to load lots of data? Or how to insert to multiple tables in a single transaction? In the second case a *single* method, with a single connection and different queries is the correct solution. You can put each query into a separate method if you like, as long as you pass the *connection* as a parameter.

Comment: Because in future time my process will become like 1. Load Data from Server A table A and table B. 2. Insert into Data to Server B table A and table B. 3. Move Server A data to table C and table D. 4. Make sure everything ok, Delete Data in Server A table A and table B.

Comment: So that's why I want to use TransactionScope, I need to make sure previous 3 action in complete without error than I can delete my orignal data. And there are 3-5 different server need to do this action. That's why I want to use parallel work.

Comment: That's a *completely* different question from the one you posted and that's not parallel work either. More importantly, you can't just use TransactionScope and get a distributed transaction that covers all servers. You need a service that will act as a transaction coordinator (like MS DTC).  The connections will remain open for the duration of that distributed transaction. Fun fact, Oracle's driver doesn't support them while [MySqlConnector does](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/).

Comment: BTW MySqlBulkCopy works with an `IDataReader` or `DataTable`, so you can read data from one server with `ExecuteReaderAsync` and send it directly to the target.

Answer (score 3):

The likely reason is that you are disposing/completing the transaction before both SQL calls have completed.

The idea of running multiple operations in parallel, inside a single transaction, seem weird to me, but I'm not a database expert. Are you sure you should not be using separate transaction scopes for each operation?

You should at the very least move the Task.Wait inside the scope:

```
disTaskList.Add(CallSQL1(connStr));
disTaskList.Add(CallSQL2(connStr));
await Task.WhenAll(disTaskList);
transactionScope.Complete();
```

Or just skip the async stuff, In the version of MySql I'm using truly asynchronous operations are not supported, and they will block in practice.

Comment: Yes! The connector provider from MySQL is not working on async stuff. Someone improve this problem and release a new one called MySqlConnector. Now MySqlConnector download rate is more than MySql.Data on NuGet.

Comment: Async or not, the very fact the code is trying to use a distributed transaction is a very strong smell. Why run 2 queries concurrently and *then* try to put them in the same transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach was better. Your second solution with `Task.WhenAll` completes the transaction when the tasks will still be executing.

The transaction completion may be attempted mid operation, which you really do not want.

The whole point of a transaction is to ensure that the database does not commit part of a sequence of operations that need to occur together.

If your `CallSQL1` & `CallSQL2` don't need to be committed together then you do not need a transaction at all.

If you want to stick with `Task.WhenAll`, then you must await before the transaction is complete.

```
List<Task> disTaskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (string connStr in connectionString)
{
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        try
        {
            disTaskList.Add(CallSQL1(connStr));
            disTaskList.Add(CallSQL2(connStr));
            await Task.WhenAll(disTaskList);
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call Sql Error Excption = ");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update:

If you want the calls to each database to be parallel rather than just the operations within a single DB, then you could try this kind of approach:

Create a method that makes all of the required DB calls.

```
private async Task CallSqlMethods(string connStr)
{
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        try
        {
            await CallSQL1(connStr);
            await CallSQL2(connStr);
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call Sql Error Excption = ");
        }
    }
}
```

Then call the method like this:

```
List<Task> disTaskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (string connStr in connectionString)
{
    disTaskList.Add(CallSqlMethods(connStr));
}
await Task.WhenAll(disTaskList);
```

Comment: Yes. It can work, but a little shortcoming is not all database's CallSQL1 and CallSQL2 become parallel work, only 1 database's CallSQL1 and CallSQL2 become parallel work.

Answer (score 0):

The approaches are wrong at the root - executing inefficient queries concurrently often results in *slower* performance as the connections block each other. That's especially true with INSERTs that actually try to write to the same disk blocks.

Using a `TransactionScope` over multiple connections is far worse, as it requires a distributed transaction that covers all connections. Those connections will remain open until the distributed transaction itself completes, increasing the chance of blocking.

In this particular case, performance can be increased several orders or even by orders of magnitude, using a single connection by (slowest to fastest):

1. Batching multiple INSERT commands into one. Essentially, the SQL string contains multiple INSERTs. This reduces conflict and network latency, eg :

```
INSERT INTO machine_info (..) VALUES ('CCC','099','AOT','2020-02-02 02:00:00');
INSERT INTO machine_info (..) VALUES ('CCC','099','AOT','2020-02-02 02:00:00');
```

2. Creating a single INSERT with multiple rows

```
INSERT INTO machine_info (..) 
VALUES 
    ('CCC','099','AOT','2020-02-02 02:00:00'),
    ('CCC','099','AOT','2020-02-02 02:00:00'),
    ('CCC','099','AOT','2020-02-02 02:00:00');
```

3. Using [MySqlBulkCopy](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/) or [MySqlBulkLoader](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkloadertype/) to import data using MySQL's [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loading-tables.html) behind the scenes

```
var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "some_table_name";
var result = await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
```

or

```
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("...;AllowLoadLocalInfile=True");
await connection.OpenAsync();
var bulkLoader = new MySqlBulkLoader(connection)
{
    FileName = @"C:\Path\To\file.csv",
    TableName = "destination",
    CharacterSet = "UTF8",
    NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1,
    FieldTerminator = ",",
    FieldQuotationCharacter = '"',
    FieldQuotationOptional = true,
    Local = true,
}
var rowCount = await bulkLoader.LoadAsync();
```

Comment: The code on my post is simply code for this post, My really sql command is like your point 2. "Creating a single INSERT with multiple rows".

Comment: @TYS in the question comments you described a completely different scenario - a true distributed transaction covering multiple servers. Oracle's driver doesn't support this, MySqlConnector does, and the *real* code you need is `ExecuteQueryAsync` with `Task.WhenAll`. The connections will be kept open as long as the TransactionScope is active so it's better to *not* create the connections inside methods, but explicitly control transactions and connections at the top

Comment: I had mentioned it is in future will change process. That's why I need to improve my code from await to Task.WhenAll.Aand my post is I got error when ExecuteNonQueryAsync with Task.WhenAll.